# Idiomatic Play Framework URL design for child items

Tags: scala, url, playframework, playframework-2.0

Newbie Play Framework question on URL design: I’m looking for what is more idiomatic for the Play framework although I suppose this could in some ways be a more general URL design question.

These are not my real entities but let’s say you have collections you can edit with things like:

```
GET /collections/:id controllers.Collections.edit(id: Long)
POST /collections/:id controllers.Collections.update(id: Long)
POST /collections/:id/delete controllers.Collections.delete(id: Long)
```

And now each collection can have items.  The items are in the database with their own ID’s, but they also have the ID of the parent collection with a foreign key constraint.

So I could see having these:

```
GET /collections/:collection/items controllers.Items.list(collection: Long)
GET /collections/:collection/items/new controllers.Items.create(collection: Long)
POST /collections/:collection/items controllers.Items.save(collection: Long)
```

But then to edit or delete individual items that already exist and thus I can get the collection ID for the item with just the item ID do I want this:

```
GET /items/:id controllers.Items.edit(id: Long)
POST /items/:id controllers.Items.update(id: Long)
POST /items/:id/delete controllers.Items.delete(id: Long)
```

or do I instead want to do something like this?:

```
GET /collections/:collection/items/:id controllers.Items.edit(collection:Long, id: Long)
POST /collections/:collection/items/:id controllers.Items.update(collection:Long, id: Long)
POST /collections/:collection/items/:id/delete controllers.Items.delete(collection:Long, id: Long)
```

One thought that comes to mind is what if I had used a compound key (for better or for worse).  Should I use the second set to isolate the interface from the fact that I only need the item ID with the current schema?  Or is that second set totally bogus and wasteful?  In theory it allows a URL with the wrong collection ID for the existing item (you could check for that, but still).

(Note I would use more RESTful PUT/DELETE above but I’m using normal HTML forms at the moment)

(Sorry if this is a FAQ, I couldn't really find anything like this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Play 2.0 there is no built-in auto controller/action route (as it was possible in Play 1.x) so *de facto* there is no defined pattern for the routes.

That means, that you can do your own pattern and only you have to make sure that routes are valid. There are some of my thoughts and practicies:

You should not use i.e. redundant prefixes like `/collections/` or `/items/`:

```
http://domain.tld/presentation/collections/1/items/1
```

cause if user will delete last segment in the address bar it will point to nowhere

```
http://domain.tld/presentation/collections/1/items (404 as no such route)
```

Instead try to build URLs that are prepared to serve something sensible even if user will modify it:

```
http://domain.tld/presentation/1/1 (display single item 1 in collection 1)
http://domain.tld/presentation/1   (list of items in collection 1)
http://domain.tld/presentation     (list of collections)
http://domain.tld/                 (main page)
```

of course in such case it would be better if you'll create string keys to identify the records in database to make links user friendly:

```
http://domain.tld/t-shirts/autumn-2012/play-geeks-shirt-red-xl
http://domain.tld/tasks/project-1/prepare-correct-routes
```

Of course if you don't trust the string identifiers you can make link like the Stack Overflow, where penultimate segment is numeric ID, and last one is only a string for search engines and humans and has no meaning for searching the record (open that link `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719857` and it will bring you current question as well)

I personally prefer string identifiers without additional numeric ID in the frontend, however it requires checking if it's unique in selected path and storing additional data in DB.

For backend I'd suggest using stable prefix at the beginning and separate controller (it's just easier to set one authorization rule for whole controller, than annotating many actions). Of course using string identifiers for editing records is redundant effort:

```
http://domain.tld/admin/1         (list of items from first collection)
http://domain.tld/admin/1/edit    (edit form for first collection)
http://domain.tld/admin/1/1       (edit form for item 1 in first collection \), 
       it hasn't got subitems so there's no need to display its preview first

http://domain.tld/admin/1/1/edit  (alternative, same action as above)
       in this case you should prepare redirect from admin/1/1 to admin/1/1/edit,
       otherwise you'll get same form available on two URL's (for each record) 
       which can be confusing
```

`delete`, `save`, `update` actions usually goes as last segment (although to be more RESTful it should be declared as ie. DELETE route without `/delete` suffix at the end)

```
 http://domain.tld/admin/1/1/delete
```

Anyway if you are going to use ie GET for deleting records it's good idea to add some calculated hash to the URL and check it before deleting object from DB. It isn't authorization mechanism as there are better things for it, it's just allow you to make sure that you won't delete record accidentally by writing the url manually, so it can be for an example MD5 hash of the records ID:

```
 http://domain.tld/admin/1/1/delete?confirm=a76fe878988ced8...
```

Finally if both, collections and items aren't correlated strictly, you can just make links for editing them in separate 'url-spaces':

```
 http://domain.tld/admin/collections/1/edit
 http://domain.tld/admin/items/1/edit
 http://domain.tld/admin/contacts/1/edit
 http://domain.tld/admin/offices/1/edit...
```

In such case it would be good enough if you'll prepare correct navlinks, most probably you don't need to care to much that you as an admin will manipulate the URL's if you have clean and comfortable navigation.